# How to calculate windowed mean squared displacement for multiple particles?

Tags: diffusion, molecular-dynamics

I'm new to molecular dynamics and I find this equation pretty confusing:

$MSD(\tau)=<r(t+\tau)-r(t)>$

For example take a structure with N mobile ions (e.g. oxygen particles). In different articles I found different ways of calculating MSD and I'm very confused which is the right way.

My data is of shape (k, N, 3). k is time moments, N is number of oxygen particles and 3 is dimensions x, y, z.

My way is that firstly I construct an array in which each element corresponds to different window size (lag times) and then in loop for every distinct particle i'm gathering sum of squared differences between next positions (e.g. for lag time = 5s, position between one oxygen particle in t=10s and t=15s). Then I'm dividing it by the number of oxygen particles and then adding it to another sum. I'm adding to this another sum multiple times (actually this many times as the difference won't go out of scope) and then divide it by (number of time steps minus window size) and this is my MSD value for perticular lag time.

This is my algorithm:

```
def Calculate_Windowed_MSD(positions, N, k):
MSD_tau = np.array([])

for window_size in range(1, k):
    sum_time_step = 0
    for time_step in range(0, k-window_size):
        sumation = 0
        for particle in range(0, N):
            sumation+=Calculate_Norm(positions[time_step+window_size][particle]-positions[time_step][particle])**2
        sum_time_step+= sumation/N
    MSD_tau = np.append(MSD_tau, sum_time_step/(k-window_size))

return MSD_tau
```

Where k is number of time moments, N - number of oxygen particles

I don't know if there are any errors, but I get weird results for diffusion coefficients. Also I want to understand how to change this algorithm into considering also correlation between different oxygen particles. Can anyone help?

Comment: If you haven't found a fix for your code, you might try using [Freud](https://freud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/introduction.html#), a Python package with an inbuilt function for computing the mean-squared distance (MSD) of your data. They have many [examples](https://github.com/glotzerlab/freud-examples/tree/master), including one that computes the MSD of some given data, [here](https://github.com/glotzerlab/freud-examples/blob/master/examples/LAMMPS-LJ-MSD/LAMMPS-LJ-MSD.ipynb). I am not affiliated with the creators, but I have used the package myself without much difficulty to co